# Taylor's Theorem with Remainder fails when sequence has zero terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

If we try to calculate the remainder of a series such as $0+\frac{x}{3}+0-\frac{x^3}{5}+0+\frac{x^5}{7}+0...$

Does the theorem fail?

I was trying to find the remainder centered at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ after the first two *nonzero* terms. Since the first two nonzero terms are at $n=1$ and $n=3$, I tried to find $R_3(\frac{1}{2})$ and I ended up with $0$ (incorrect).

However if I move on to the next nonzero term and calculate $R_4(\frac{1}{2})$ then I get the correct answer of $\frac{1}{224}$.

Is there supposed to be a stipulation in the theorem? I'm failing to see how $R_3(\frac{1}{2})=0$ doesn't break the theorem. Thanks!

*EDIT*

Well I'm still a bit confused so let me post the actual question and my procedure:
[image: question p1]

[image]

So the actual function $g$ is not given. However, by comparing the terms of the sequence to the definition of McLaurin/Taylor series, namely:

$f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\frac{f''(a)(x-a)^2}{2!}+...$

I am able to determine that $a=0,f(a)=0,f'(a)=\frac{1!}{3},f''(a)=0,f^{(3)}(a)=\frac{-3!}{5},f^{(4)}(a)=0,f^{(5)}(a)=\frac{5!}{7}$

Then I apply Taylor's Theory with Remainder, which says:

$R_n(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1}$

It says $c$ can be anything between $a$ and $x$, so I let $c=0$ and start plugging in to get

$R_3(\frac{1}{2})=\frac{0}{24}(\frac{1}{2})^4=0$

$R_4(\frac{1}{2})=\frac{\frac{120}{7}}{120}(\frac{1}{2})^5=\frac{1}{224}$

Comment: How did you bound the error and get zero? I suspect that you are misapplying Taylor's theorem. In particular, you will need some sort of bound for the 4th derivative of the function, and it's not clear to me that you even know what the function is.

Comment: See edits. I don't know what you mean by "bound the error", but you can now see how I got 0. And no, I do not know what the function is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial suspicion was correct. The theorem should have a stipulation: The Taylor Remainder can only be calculated using the next *non-zero* term.

Answer (score 0):

You have misundestood "after the first two non-zero terms." The function is $$f(x)=0+\frac{x}{3}+0-\frac{x^3}{5}+0+\frac{x^5}{7}+0...$$ The Taylor series is $$f(1/2)+(x-1/2)f'(1/2)+\frac{(x-1/2)^2}{2!}f''(1/2)+\frac{(x-1/2)^3}{3!}f'''(1/2)+...$$ You are asked to find the remainder after the first two non-zero terms of this series, not after the first two terms of the series defining f(x).

Comment: I don't believe that I did what you are saying. Sorry but maybe I didn't give enough info initially. Please see edits to original question. I'm still failing to see why I'm getting $R_3(\frac{1}{2})=0$. Thanks!